# How to use an existing Environment variable in subprocess.Popen()

Tags: python, subprocess

**Scenario**

In my python script I need to run an executable file as a subprocess with x number of command line parameters which the executable is expecting.

Example:

- EG 1: myexec.sh param1 param2
- EG 2: myexec.sh param1 $MYPARAMVAL

The executable and parameters are not known as these are configured and retrieved from external source (xml config) at run time.

My code is working when the parameter is a known value (EG 1) and configured, however the expectation is that a parameter could be an environment variable and configured as such, which should be interpreted at run time.(EG 2)

In the example below I am using echo as a substitute for myexec.sh to demonstrate the scenario.
This is simplified to demonstrate issue. 'cmdlst' is built from a configuration file, which could be any script with any number of parameters and values which could be a value or environment variable.

**test1.py**

```
import subprocess
import os

cmdlst = ['echo','param1','param2']

try:
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmdlst,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    jobpid = proc.pid
    stdout_value, stderr_value = proc.communicate()
except (OSError, subprocess.CalledProcessError) as err:
    raise

print stdout_value
```

**RESULT TEST 1**

*python test1.py*

--> param1 param2

**test2.py**

```
import subprocess
import os

cmdlst = ['echo','param1','$PARAM']

try:
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmdlst,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    jobpid = proc.pid
    stdout_value, stderr_value = proc.communicate()
except (OSError, subprocess.CalledProcessError) as err:
    raise

print stdout_value
```

**RESULT TEST 2**

*export PARAM=param2*
*echo $PARAM*

--> param2
*python test2.py*

--> param1 $PARAM

I require Test 2 to produce the same result as Test 1, considering that $PARAM would only be known at run-time and need to be retrieved from the current environment.

I welcome your advice.

Comment: does `param2 = os.environ["PARAM"]` do what you want, or not quite? I never remember which arguments to pass to `Popen` to get the quoting correct - the issue is it's quoting your args such that they don't expand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do:

```
cmdlist = ['echo','param',os.environ["PARAM"]]
```

Or:

```
cmdlist = ['echo','param1','$PARAM']
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmdlist,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, env={'PARAM':os.environ['PARAM'])
```

Comment: What if the env var name 'PARAM' is in a str variable. So needs to be evaluated.?

Comment: @user3927078 You can do give `env={'PARAM':'String'}` too

Comment: I can't make this work in either Python 2 or 3 - what am I doing wrong?

`>>> cmdlist = ['echo','param1','$PARAM']`
`>>> proc = subprocess.Popen(cmdlist,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, env={'PARAM':"ads"})`
`>>> proc.communicate()`
`('param1 $PARAM\n', None)`

Answer (score 11):

If you want to have the shell expand environment variables, you have to set `shell=True`

```
subprocess.Popen('echo param1 $PARAM', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Alternatively, you could just query the environment variable yourself when constructing the command, and then there is no need for shell expansion

```
subprocess.Popen(['echo', 'param1', os.environ['PARAM']], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not access the environment variable using `$VAR`. You'd use `os.environ[..]` instead:

```
cmdlst = ['echo','param1',os.environ['PARAM']]
```